# ¿Se pueden tener dos webs hechas en el mismo hosting?

Tags: hosting, cpanel, instalacion

Quisiera hacer la siguiente consulta. Tengo un hosting, con un determinado dominio. En el tengo una aplicación de laravel 7 corriendo actualmente.

La pregunta es si podría tener dos instalaciones de laravel distintas corriendo bajo ese dominio. Por ejemplo:

https://midomino.es/blog  -> Una aplicación de laravel
https://midomino.es/admin  -> otra aplicación de laravel

No tengo claro si se puede hacer esto, tengo subidos actualmente todos los ficheros de laravel a la raíz del dominio y el contenido de la carpeta `public` de laravel en `public_html`, pero de esta manera no veo la forma de tener otra instalación distinta.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Sí, tendrías que usas los ´Alias´ de `Apache`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/midomain.com/blog/public_html
Alias /admin /var/www/midomain.com/admin/public_html
```

Básicamente lo que le dices ahí a Apache es que cuando muestre `/admin` o `/blog` cargue lo que exista en las respectivas rutas asociadas

Aquí te dejo la documentación de Apache para que veas como funciona: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/mod/mod_alias.html

Veo también que como etiqueta has usado `cpanel`, te paso un link donde puedes ver como hacerlo en ese panel de control.

https://swapps.com/es/blog/personalice-virtualhosts-en-whm-cpanel/

De todas formas, dentro de `cpanel` si puedes editar o extender el `Virtualhost` siempre podrás usar la documentación de Apache como referencia y crear tu propio alias.